# CORS in react app and django restframework

Tags: reactjs

We have a rest api built with Django and as client we gonna use react-js application to get data from server .

Our problem is Django API does not support CORS headers so I want to disable this option in react.

How can i disable React CORS the way react dont check cors headers ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable CORS in the client. It's built into the browser itself. If your API does not support adding custom headers you can standup a proxy in front of the API that will allow you to add the headers. In a standard application you would serve pages from the same domain as the API in which case you don't need CORS headers.  If all your services are internal it is also common to use a reverse proxy to serve all calls over the same origin anyway.